# NameError: name 'discord' is not defined

Tags: python, pycharm, discord, discord.py

VS code has failed me so I switched to PyCharm. I installed Discord.py correctly, and importing it worked. But trying to make a custom status for my bot produces the error:

```
File "C:\Users\me\Desktop\Projects\TooB\TooB.py", line 8, in on_ready
discord.Activity(name="message", type=0) NameError: name 'discord' is not defined
```

This is my entire thing so far:

```
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "toob!")

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot online.")
    discord.Activity(name="message", type=0)




bot.run('TOKEN')
```

Does anybody have any idea how to fix this??

Comment: Pycharm should have warned you about that line and also offered a solution.

Comment: @Selcuk It did warn me, which is what I posted, but offered no solution.

Comment: That is not a Pycharm warning, it's a Python error. Warnings are displayed directly on the source code. Click the red underlined word `discord` and then click the exclamation mark. It will offer you to import that name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you will have to import the Discord module. To do that:

```py
import discord
```

That needs to be added to the top of your code. In addition, the status needs to be set correctly. For how to do that:

```py
# Setting `Playing` status
await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name="a game"))

# Setting `Streaming` status
await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Streaming(name="My Stream", url=my_twitch_url))

# Setting `Listening` status
await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.listening, name="a song"))

# Setting `Watching` status
await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.watching, name="a movie"))
```

Comment: If that works, please upvote and accept!

Comment: It didn't give an error, but the custom status didn't work so that sucked. ://

Comment: You are creating the status incorrectly. I edited my post above, see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks, can you upvote as well? (Sorry for asking)